# Android Studio crashes in Mac OS Monterey Beta 6

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

So I recently updated my MacBook Air M1 chip to the latest version of Mac OS Monterey and suddenly my Android Studio started crashing because of which I can't connect my emulator or use Flutter with it. Can someone help me with it?
Here are my logs -

```
Process:               studio [53499]
Path:                  /Volumes/VOLUME/*/Android Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio
Identifier:            com.google.android.studio
Version:               2020.3 (AI-203.7717.56.2031.7678000) 
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-09-15 13:29:43.4753 +0530
OS Version:            macOS 12.0 (21A5506j)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        5ACCD76D-EE29-30BD-078E-17070264723F

Sleep/Wake UUID:       23925D3A-0748-4C60-B3F3-19C83A953526

Time Awake Since Boot: 1000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       271 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        3

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000400000000
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000400000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Region Info: 0x400000000 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 6796312577  Bytes before following region: 14763950080
      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      unused shlib __TEXT         26791e000-26ae88000    [ 53.4M] r--/r-- SM=COW  ... this process
--->  GAP OF 0x505178000 BYTES
      VM_ALLOCATE (reserved)      770000000-778000000    [128.0M] rw-/rwx SM=NUL  ...(unallocated)

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
```

The entire thing is quite long, but these are the top few lines. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and upgrading to monterey beta 7 solved the issue I hope it does for you too.

Answer (score 0):

In my own case, I got a prompt to update my Android studio after switching to Mac OS Monterey. Before downloading the update, I selected the wrong processor (Apple/Intel) and that was why my Android Studio was crashing on installation.

I hope this helps someone out there.

To check your processor type, click on the Apple logo on the top left corner of your Mac and select the first menu option that appears: **About this Mac**, the appropriate processor type would be displayed.